# Android Second Activity Error

Tags: android, google-maps

So My application Consists of first activity which shows some text, and on action bar there is a File menu, in which I put My location option.

I call another activity in mainActivity with onOptionItemSelected as follows:

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_photo:
            openPhoto();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_video:
            openVideo();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_map:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, GPSTracker.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

in manifest i declare the second activity as follows:

```
     <activity
        android:name="com.example.locateme.GPSTracker"
        android:label="@string/app_name" > 
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

and in GPSTracker.java i write this:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gpstracker);
}
```

also there is my code for finding the location. 
I am running the app, bu when i press `My Location` option the app crashes.

[Here are the logcat errors after removing intent for GPS activity](http://pastebin.com/QDPnYfB8)

The [full code of the app is here](http://pastebin.com/LZyDtnVL), in case there may be something i missed.
Do i call the second activity in the wrong way?

Comment: post the logcat error

Comment: i added the logcat in the question. thank you.

Comment: its not loading page your lagcat

Comment: cant instantiate class `...GPSTRacker` no empty constructor. i can see this is the problem. cosidering my code, what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.locateme.GPSTracker; no empty constructor
```

is quite obvious error.

Somewhere in your GPSTracker class you have a definition like

```
public GPSTracker(SomeClass referenceName) {
     //...
}
```

This block of code should be removed or replaced with constructor without params. The first option if prefered: use `onCreate` as your constructor.

Comment: yes i have. 
`public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}`

Comment: can you please suggest me how do i modify it?

Comment: @LuchFilip You may remove `private Context mContext;` from your code and use `this` instead. And of course remove constructor too. `getLocation` might be called from `onCreate`.

Comment: in onCreate i write `this.getLocation();` and then erase `public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.getLocation();
}` but i use mContext later. 
how do i change the code so that i have mContext too?

Comment: @LuchFilip Since `GPSTracker` is extending `Activity` and `Activity` is a kind of `Context`, you may use `this` anywhere you would use `mContext`.

Answer (score 1):

First, remove the intent-filter for Your GPS Activity in Your Manifest.xml, here You had set both activities (Main and GPS) as a launcher. Set only one Activity as LAUNCHER and MAIN. And then it will be good to see LogCat Output to know why it crashs

Comment: i removed the intent filter for gps activity and uploaded the logcat. thank you for your help.